# How to compare the data input from arduino with libreoffice Calc in python

Tags: pi-3, python, arduino

Was my code for read the libreoffice cal file was right?And i wan send back true or false to arduino after compare the input with cal file. When i key in the number from arduino,no matter correct or wrong the program just throw it. in this case, i have a file with the IDnumber. i wan compare the users is the right person in the list.

My Python Code:

```
import serial
import csv
arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)

    while(1==1):
        if (arduino.inWaiting()>0:
            myData = arduino.readline()
            print myData
            with open('idnum.csv') as csvDatafile:
                csvReader = csv.reader(csvDatafile)
                found = False
                line = arduino.readline()
            found = True
            arduino.write("True")
```

My Arduino Code:

```cpp
void state0(){
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Welcome");
    char Key = mykeypad.getKey();
    //key in ID 
    if (Key != NO_KEY) {
        key1[z] = Key;
        z++;
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.print(key1);
        Serial.println(key1);
        //send to raspberrypi 
        if(z==11) {
            if(Serial.available()) {
                char inByte = Serial.read();
                //send to python to compare char received1 = true;
                // received true from python state = 1;
            }
            else {
                state = 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My CSV File

```
50212215000 50212215001 50212215002
```

Comment: could you paste your code please, and explain what is actually happening. "correct or wrong the program just throw it" No idea what you are talking about. please update your question and include the errors.

Comment: when i key in correct idnumber or wrong,my arduino will jump to the correct state.

Comment: can you please paste your code and not upload any more pictures of it.

Comment: and also paste some of your csv file

Comment: here is arduino code: void state0(){   lcd.setCursor(0,0); lcd.print("Welcome");   char Key = mykeypad.getKey();     //key in ID
    if (Key != NO_KEY)
  {     key1[z] = Key;     z++;     lcd.setCursor(0,1);     lcd.print(key1);
    Serial.println(key1);  //send to raspberrypi
    if(z==11)    {        if(Serial.available())
    {   char inByte = Serial.read();     //send to python to compare
      char  received1 = true;         // received true from python
      state = 1;    }    else    {      state = 2;    }  }  }   }

Comment: this is the idnumber inside csv file:50212215000
50212215001
50212215002
50212215003
50212215004
50212215005
50212215006
50212215007
50212215008
50212215008

Answer (score 2):

Your Python loop will always return true, and you never search for the string in your csv file.

Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import serial
import csv
arduino_data = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)

csvFile = "idnum.csv"

while True:
    if (arduino.inWaiting()>0:
        myArduinoData = arduino.readline()
        print myArduinoData

        with open(csvFile) as csvDatafile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvDatafile, delimiter="\t")
            for row in reader:
                if (row[0] == myArduinoData):
                    print "True",  row[0]
                    arduino.write("1")
                else:
                    print "False"
```

Arduino Code:

```
    void state0(){
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("Welcome");
        char Key = mykeypad.getKey();
        //key in ID 
        if (Key != NO_KEY) {
            key1[z] = Key;
            z++;
            lcd.setCursor(0,1);
            lcd.print(key1);
            Serial.println(key1);
            //send to raspberrypi 
            if(z==11) {
                while(Serial.available()) {
                        //input= Serial.readString();// read the incoming data as string
                        char inByte = Serial.read();

                    if (char==1) {
                        state = 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        state = 2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

also save your csv like this

```
50212215000
50212215001 
50212215002 
50212215003 
50212215004 
50212215005 
50212215006 
50212215007 
50212215008 
50212215008
```

Comment: when i follow the python code above,when i pressing the id it just show out false..than i change put 1 in row (row[1] == myArduinoData), it show the list index out of range.

Comment: row[0]  is indicating the first row in the CSV file, as there is only 1 row if you try to tell it row[1] that is the second row, which does not exist.  as for reading out false thats because arduino.write("True") is sending the string "True" back to the Arduino , i will update my answer

Comment: is my arduino code wrong,cause my arduino nothing show out false or true..it just stay at the number i last key in

Comment: I added arduino code to my answer for you, did that help you?

Comment: Sorry Dr.Rabbit..the input should be declare as what variable? i declare it as char, it has error say cant convert string to char.

Comment: I have updated the Arduino code for you.

Comment: still no have feedback from python. my arduino just stop there when i finis key in idnumber.

Comment: got error when (char ==1), the error is expected primary-expression before 'char'

Comment: Check this tutorial [arduino-serial-communication](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Arduino-Serial-Communication/) start a new project and make sure you have the correct ports ect, then start adding the key checking stuff